# How to display custom entity in editor form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 project using Razor. I have next entities:

Offer:

```
public class Offer
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Added { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public Decimal Price { get; set; }

    public String Address { get; set; }

    public virtual OfferCategory OfferCategory { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

OfferCategory:

```
public class OfferCategory
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Offer> Offers { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I'm trying to make form for adding new Offer with the DropDownListFor(OfferCategory). In this dropDownList will appear all existing offerCategories in db. Here how far I get:

AddOffer Action in controller:

```
var categories = _context.OfferCategory.ToList();
List<SelectListItem> OfferCategories = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var offerCategory in categories)
{
    OfferCategories.Add(new SelectListItem() { Selected = false, Text =  offerCategory.Name, Value = offerCategory.Id.ToString()});
}
ViewBag.OfferCategories = OfferCategories;
```

And here is View:

```
 //... A lot of things
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfferCategory)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.OfferCategory,  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OfferCategories)
</div>
//... A lot of things
```

When in the form appears all the OfferCategories as well but when I click submit button my POST AddOffer(Offer offer) handler didn't get the OfferCategory which was selected in the form. How can I do make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfferCategory)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.OfferCategory,  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OfferCategories)
</div>
```

You need to change to

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfferCategory)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.OfferCategory.Id,  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OfferCategories)
</div>
```

Note the model=>model.OfferCategory.Id instead of model=>model.OfferCategory

Comment: Hm, it's a interesting idea. I will check it.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you specify in dropdownlist "model=>model.OfferCategory", which generates html close to 'select name="model.OfferCategory"'. When the form gets posted to your action "AddOffer(Offer offer)" asp.net mvc model binder tries to create OfferCategory object but it can't do that becaue all it knows is a category id. What you need to do is to change the way you craete dropdown list in view to: 
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.OfferCategory.Id,(IEnumerable)ViewBag.OfferCategories). After doing that you will get OfferCategory object created with Id property populated.
I hope that will help you.

Comment: Can you give some code how I should change the way I create dropdownList in view? I understand what the isue is, but I can't find the way to fix it

Comment: I know this way: I can add the SelectedCategoryId to my `Offer` entity and in `AddOffer` handler to get the OfferCategory by this ID. But is this right way?